# Цвет границы вокруг кнопки

Tags: javascript, css

Пытаюсь выставить нужный мне цвет линий вокруг кнопки, но столкнулся с проблемой. При установки цвета, цвет левой и верхней линии устанавливается нормально, а цвет правой и нижней границы смешивается с другим, непонятно откуда взявшимся цветом.

Вот CSS:

```
.someClass {
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-top-width: 1px;  
    border-left-width: 0px; 
    border-top-color: #B855C5;
    border-bottom-color: #C332DA !important;
    border-right-color: #C332DA !important;    
    border-left-color: #C332DA !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У кнопок по умолчанию border-style стоит как outset. Поменяйте на solid. Или воспользуйтесь предыдущим ответом.

Answer (score 4):

Потому что, border-left-width: **0** и лучше пользуйтесь короткой записью.

```
border: 1px solid #с332da;
```

а для верхней потом пропишите

```
border-top: 1px solid #b855c5;
```